# If Else statement result in VB.net is random

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, if-statement, datagridview

My If Else statement in VB.net is randomly displaying either of the If or ElseIf condition that I made.

What I'm trying to do is when a DataGridView checkbox is selected and the LinkLabel is clicked, The system will get the row which is selected and it will update the "EditTime" column to either "ds" or "en" depending on what is already in the column

So, if the data in the "EditTime" column is set to "ds", the If Else condition should change it to "en" and vice versa.

```
Dim en As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Roster1]", myConnection)
        Dim d As OleDbDataReader = en.ExecuteReader
        Dim edt As String = ""
        While d.Read
            edt = d("EditTime").ToString
        End While


        Dim CheckedRows =
            (
                From Rows In AdminTabDisplay.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
                Where CBool(Rows.Cells("ck").Value) = True
            ).ToList
        If CheckedRows.Count > 0 Then

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In CheckedRows
            sb.AppendLine(row.Cells("Employee ID").Value.ToString)

        Next

            If edt = "ds" Then
                Dim st As String = sb.ToString
                Dim value As Integer = CInt(st)
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Roster1] SET [EditTime] = @pw WHERE [Employee ID] = @v", myConnection)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", "en")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", value)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Edit enabled!")

            ElseIf edt = "en" Then
                Dim st As String = sb.ToString
                Dim value As Integer = CInt(st)
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Roster1] SET [EditTime] = @pw WHERE [Employee ID] = @v", myConnection)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", "ds")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", value)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Edit disabled!")
            End If
```

This is my code. Yet, the output seems to be a bit randomized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many rows are in [Roster1] table? Because with statements:

```
    While d.Read
        edt = d("EditTime").ToString
    End While
```

in edt you have always the value of last row. Is correct?

EDIT:

Try this code:

```
    Dim CheckedRows =
        (
            From Rows In AdminTabDisplay.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
            Where CBool(Rows.Cells("ck").Value) = True
        ).ToList
    If CheckedRows.Count > 0 Then

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In CheckedRows

        Dim st as String = row.Cells("Employee ID").Value.ToString
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(st)

        Dim en As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Roster1] WHERE [Employee ID] = @v", myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", value)
        Dim d As OleDbDataReader = en.ExecuteReader
        Dim edt As String = d("EditTime").ToString

        If edt = "ds" Then
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Roster1] SET [EditTime] = @pw WHERE [Employee ID] = @v", myConnection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", "en")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", value)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Edit enabled!")

        ElseIf edt = "en" Then
            Dim st As String = sb.ToString
            Dim value As Integer = CInt(st)
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Roster1] SET [EditTime] = @pw WHERE [Employee ID] = @v", myConnection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", "ds")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", value)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Edit disabled!")
        End If
    Next
```

EDIT (I added the WHILE loop in it and edited some variables and it works!):

```
Dim CheckedRows =
    (
        From Rows In AdminTabDisplay.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
        Where CBool(Rows.Cells("ck").Value) = True
    ).ToList
    If CheckedRows.Count > 0 Then


        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In CheckedRows

            Dim st As String = row.Cells("Employee ID").Value.ToString
            Dim value As Integer = CInt(st)

            Dim en As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Roster1] WHERE [Employee ID] = @v", myConnection)
            en.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", value)
            Dim d As OleDbDataReader = en.ExecuteReader
            Dim edt As String = ""

            While d.Read
                edt = d("EditTime").ToString
            End While

            If edt = "ds" Then
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Roster1] SET [EditTime] = @pw WHERE [Employee ID] = @v", myConnection)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", "en")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", value)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Edit enabled!")

            ElseIf edt = "en" Then
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Roster1] SET [EditTime] = @pw WHERE [Employee ID] = @v", myConnection)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", "ds")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", value)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Edit disabled!")
            End If
        Next

    End If
```

Comment: currently I have 6 rows in it. But it will increase eventually because I am just using dummy data.

So edt will only get the last row?

Comment: Yes, of course. You have always the last value, not the edt value of current Eployee ID. You have to change first query as `Dim en As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Roster1] WHERE [Employee ID] = xx", myConnection)` and move it in foreach statement.

Comment: After I moved it in the foreach statement, should I remove the While Loop?

And how will I call the variable **edt** outside of the foreach statement? @Andrea

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see the next statement. You have to do the same work for every checked row, I think. So, if it is so, move if/elseif block in foreach block. I edit my answer with code.

Comment: I tried your prescribed code, yet it produces an error saying: no data exists in row/column @Andrea

Comment: I edited your code and placed an improvement above. It was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if intentionally you are doing this. For **If edt = "ds" Then**  en is used in the if block AddWithValue("@pw", "**en**"). 
While for **ElseIf edt = "en" Then** the elseif block refers to **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", "ds")**

Comment: yes because there is already a data in the **EditTime** column which has either a value of **'en'** or **'ds'** (which by the way means enabled or disabled, respectively) @Mukul